# Ajax pagination doesn't work with variable query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a search filter that fetch the data from mysql using ajax pagination and apply variables in the query based on the parameter value.

When I click "next" in the pagination, it fetch the date with ignoring the variables and print all the results without the condition, but when I change the variable to manual text it works and print the results with the condition.

Query with variable:

```
SELECT up.PID, up.Name, up.Avatar FROM Profile AS up
LEFT JOIN Details AS ud ON ud.PID = up.PID
WHERE ud.Country = '$Country' ORDER BY up.PID
```

Query with none Variable:

```
SELECT up.PID, up.Name, up.Avatar FROM Profile AS up
LEFT JOIN Details AS ud ON ud.PID = up.PID
WHERE ud.Country = 'Canada' ORDER BY up.PID
```

First PHP file file1.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results" ).load("php2.php"+window.location.search); //load initial records

    //executes code below when user click on pagination links
    $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loading-div").show(); //show loading element
        var page = $(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php",{"page":page}, function(){ //get content from PHP page
            $(".loading-div").hide(); //once done, hide loading element
        });

    });
});
</script>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Second PHP file php2.php

```
<?php
//continue only if $_POST is set and it is a Ajax request
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){

    include("define.php");  //include config file
    //Get page number from Ajax POST
    if(isset($_POST["page"])){
        $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); //filter number
        if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');} //incase of invalid page number
    }else{
        $page_number = 1; //if there's no page number, set it to 1
    }

    // Get parameters
    // User Details
    $Country = $_GET['Country'];

    //get total number of records from database for pagination
    $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
  SELECT up.PID, up.Name, up.Avatar FROM Profile AS up
LEFT JOIN Details AS ud ON ud.PID = up.PID
WHERE ud.Country = '$Country' ORDER BY up.PID
    ) as t");
    $get_total_rows = $results->fetch_row(); //hold total records in variable

    //break records into pages
    $total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);

    //get starting position to fetch the records
    $page_position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);


    //Limit our results within a specified range.
    $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT up.PID, up.Name, up.Avatar FROM Profile AS up
LEFT JOIN Details AS ud ON ud.PID = up.PID
WHERE ud.Country = '$Country' ORDER BY up.PID ASC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page");
    $results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
    $results->bind_result($PID, $Name, $Avatar); //bind variables to prepared statement

    //Display records fetched from database.
    echo '<ul class="contents">';
    while($results->fetch()){ //fetch values
        echo "<a href=\"/Profile.php?id=$PID\" onClick='Loading()'><li class=\"userlistitem\">";
        echo  "<img src='$Avatar' height='100' width='100' onerror=\"this.src = '/assets/img/noImg.png'\"/>";
        echo  "$Name  $Email $PasswordD";
        echo "</li></a>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<div align="center">';
    /* We call the pagination function here to generate Pagination link for us.
    As you can see I have passed several parameters to the function. */
    echo Profile_function($item_per_page, $page_number, $get_total_rows[0], $total_pages);
    echo '</div>';

    exit;
}
################ pagination function #########################################
function Profile_function($item_per_page, $current_page, $total_records, $total_pages)
{
    $pagination = '';
    if($total_pages > 0 && $total_pages != 1 && $current_page <= $total_pages){ //verify total pages and current page number
        $pagination .= '<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">';

        $right_links    = $current_page + 3;
        $previous       = $current_page - 3; //previous link
        $next           = $current_page + 1; //next link
        $first_link     = true; //boolean var to decide our first link

        if($current_page > 1){
            $previous_link = ($previous==0)? 1: $previous;
            $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="first page-link" href="#" data-page="1" title="First">&laquo;</a></li>'; //first link
            $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="'.$previous_link.'" title="Previous">&lt;</a></li>'; //previous link
                for($i = ($current_page-2); $i < $current_page; $i++){ //Create left-hand side links
                    if($i > 0){
                        $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="'.$i.'" title="Page'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                    }
                }
            $first_link = false; //set first link to false
        }

        if($first_link){ //if current active page is first link
            $pagination .= '<li class="page-item disabled" ><span class="page-link">'.$current_page.'</a></li>';
        }elseif($current_page == $total_pages){ //if it's the last active link
            $pagination .= '<li class="page-link active"><a>'.$current_page.'</a></li>';
        }else{ //regular current link
            $pagination .= '<li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">'.$current_page.'</span></li>';
        }

        for($i = $current_page+1; $i < $right_links ; $i++){ //create right-hand side links
            if($i<=$total_pages){
                $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="'.$i.'" title="Page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        if($current_page < $total_pages){
                $next_link = ($i > $total_pages) ? $total_pages : $i;
                $pagination .= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="'.$next_link.'" title="Next">&gt;</a></li>'; //next link
                $pagination .= '<li class="last page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="'.$total_pages.'" title="Last">&raquo;</a></li>'; //last link
        }

        $pagination .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $pagination; //return pagination links
}

?>
```

What am I missing in the code?

Your help is highly needed and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid sending the parameter like that directly to your query and instead use `bind_param`

```
$results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
       SELECT up.PID, up.Name, up.Avatar FROM Profile AS up
       LEFT JOIN Details AS ud ON ud.PID = up.PID
       WHERE ud.Country = '?' ORDER BY up.PID
    ) as t");

$results=$mysqli->bind_param($Country);
$results->execute();
```

This way is a bit safe as mysqli will try to parse the data and escape any potential string that shouldn't be there.

You can refer to this documentation for bind_params:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thank you Igor Ilic for the the answer again.
The issue is more complicated as I am using dynamic query like this `SELECT up.PID, up.Name, up.Avatar FROM Profile AS up $joins WHERE 0 = 0 $columns ORDER BY up.PID` for the filter. The above is just and example to describe the issue, and if I use the same code with none Ajax, it works fine.

Comment: If I understand your question and code correctly, you need to send the page and country parameters to your php file, but you are only receiving the page parameter ?

If that is the case, you will need to expand your js code to have something like this:

$("#results").load("fetch_pages.php",{"page":page, "country":$('#country').val()}

And than also edit the php file to accept it as a POST instead of a GET param

Comment: I'm already passing parameters through window.location.search and GET
`$("#results" ).load("fetch_pages.php"+window.location.search);`
And the PHP file is receiving it and display the results correctly but when I click next, then It will fetch with without the variables in the query.